# Delayed and detained

Tags: eldritch-horror

Say your investigator gets delayed (cannot perform any actions bare "standing up") and then get *Detained* (for example, via a Mythos card). The *Detained* condition states that the investigator can only perform one action: roll influence to escape the detention. However, this means that you cannot "stand up" thus are still delayed.

I can see these solutions: (i) Stand up, you cannot roll influence and thus get the full bore of the Detained. (ii) You roll influence thus potentially escaping the detention but are still delayed at the end of your turn. (iii) You cannot have both conditions at the same time.

Is there an official one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The influence roll on the Detained card is a **Local Action**, meaning any investigator on the space, yourself included, can roll to perform the action.  Normally, you would be able to roll on it to try to remove the **Restriction**.  However, being **Delayed** adds an additional restriction indicating that you cannot perform any actions.

I believe the question is based around if the act of standing up from being **Delayed** is an **Action**.  As the rule book states:

> A Delayed investigator cannot perform actions.

The only logical way for an investigator to cease detainment is for the act of standing up to not count as an action.

The net result for your round would be:

1. Any investigators before you, who are also on your space, can roll as a local action to try to discard your Detained card
2. On your turn, regardless of Detained status, you stand up and perform no other actions due to being Delayed
3. Any investigators after you, who are also on your space, can roll as a local action to try to discard your Detained card
4. During your encounter phase, if the Detained was not removed, flip the card and encounter the back

Comment: This is how we ran it when it came up during play... ^_~